# Error list messing with the selected entry

Tags: visual-studio-2013, error-list

Maybe it's just a stupid case of PEBKAC, but recently, when fixing C# compiler errors, I frequently run into this problem:

- I press enter on the first error (to jump to the code and fix it)
- The error gets removed from the list (still normal for JIT code)
- Previously, I would now just shortcut to the Error list, press down once, then Enter and fix the next bug. But now the list just seems to put my selection at a random error, not at the next one in the file.

I have the list sorted by error number (2nd column) which seems to coincide with File and Line sorting. I'm using VS2013.

Maybe I changed some setting by accident? Or is that a VS2013 bug? (Haven't been using it for that long, and 2008 never had that problem AFAIK)

PS: It could be the case that that problem has always existed, but I didn't notice because it doesn't happen in C++ obviously, and I didn't have such a mass of errors at once (big refactoring atm)

Comment: I sometimes have the same issue with 2012. I don't think it's a bug, but the behavior seems strange to me too and I can't find the scenario.

Comment: I use F8, does that suffer the same issue?

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't know F8. Not exactly the solution to the problem, but good to know. Though I'd still like to see the next issue in the error list in many cases because I can see the error message without hovering.